# How to Use Kivy (1.10.1) Interpreter in Pycharm (Community Edition 2018.3.5)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

I want to start learning Kivy. I have been using Pycharm as my IDE for Python programming. How can I change the default python interpreter to a kivy interpreter so pycharm can recognise kivy codes?

I have installed kivy.app and created symlinks. I have also installed kivy using pip. In my python program, I have been able to successfully import App from kivy.app and it works. But when I write code to design a widget (in this case a Box Layout), Pycharm underlines in red and doesn't execute the code.

## The following code works fine:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Widget1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widget1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

## But when I write the following code to design the Box Layout, it doesn't work. Pycharm underlines: Widget1, Button, text and Label (Error written is: Unresolved Reference)

```
<Widget1>
    Button:
        text: "Please click here"
    Label:
        text: "Button has not been clicked yet"
```

If all the codes work, after running, it's supposed to return a Box Layout split into two. One part is a clickable button with "Please click here" written on it and the other part is just a label with "Button has not been clicked yet" written on it. But now when I run, it just returns an empty Box Layout (no label, no button, no text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 2

> the Box Layout code (`<Widget1>`) still doesn't work.

## Solution

### 1) kv Filename

Since you are not using Kivy Builder to load your kv codes/file, therefore you are loading kv codes/file by name convention. Make sure your kv filename is `my.kv`

[Kv language » How to load KV](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> ***By name convention:***
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```
>
> If this file defines a Root Widget it will be attached to the App’s
>   root attribute and used as the base of the application widget tree.
>
> ***By Builder convention:***  You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string or file defines a root widget, it
>   will be returned by the method:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_string(kv_string)
> ```

### 2) kv Rule Context

In your kv file, add `:` (full colon) after class rule, `<Widget1>`

### Snippets

```
<Widget1>:
```

[Kv language » Rule Context](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

> A Kv source constitutes of *rules*, which are used to describe the
>   content of a Widget, you can have one root rule, and any number of
>   *class or template rules*.
>
> The ***root rule*** is declared by declaring the class of your root
>   widget, without any indentation, followed by : and will be set as the
>   root attribute of the App instance:
>
> ```
> Widget:
> ```
>
> A ***class rule***, declared by the name of a widget class between < >
>   and followed by :, defines how any instance of that class will be
>   graphically represented:
>
> ```
> <MyWidget>:
> ```
>
> Rules use indentation for delimitation, as python, indentation should
>   be of four spaces per level, like the python good practice
>   recommendations.

## Question 1

> But when I write code to design a widget (in this case a Box Layout),
>   Pycharm underlines in red and doesn't execute the code.

## Solution

You have to install KV Language auto-completion file.

1. Download this file, [PyCharm_kv_completion.jar](https://github.com/Zen-CODE/kivybits/blob/master/IDE/PyCharm_kv_completion.jar?raw=true).
2. At bottom-right corner of PyCharm’s Welcome window, click *Configure -> Import Settings*.
3. Select the jar file you just downloaded and PyCharm will present a dialog with filetypes ticked. Click OK.
4. Restart PyCharm for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have done this and the Box Layout code (<Widget1>) still doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure your kv filename is `my.kv`. Please check updated post for more details.

Comment: Oh yes, this is what I was missing: The filename of my kv file was something different and extension was ".py". Thank you very much for your answer. I have marked it as accepted. I can't believe it was something so simple. I've been looking for a solution for over 2 weeks! Hope I haven't tampered too much with my IDE's settings :) Cheers!